# minify frontend with minify-maven-plugin

Tags: java, maven, minify, multi-module, maven-reactor

I'm using the maven plugin `minify-maven-plugin` in order to minify my frontend project. This works fine when I go over dos box to the frontend project and execute `mvn clean install` but when I execute `mvn clean install` in the main pom in my reactor project then I get the following exception:

> Failed to execute goal com.samaxes.maven:minify-maven-plugin:1.7.4:minify (default-minify) on project my.project-frontend: Execution default-minify of goal com.samaxes.maven:minify-maven-plugin:1.7.4:minify failed: basedir ./src/main/resources/public/app/. does not exis

Does anyone know what to do in order to make this work?

Below the concerned plugin configuration:

```
<!-- minify plugin -->
    <plugin>
        <groupId>com.samaxes.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>minify-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-minify</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase><!-- When omitted defaults to 'process-resources' -->
            <configuration>
              <charset>UTF-8</charset>
              <skipMerge>true</skipMerge>
              <nosuffix>true</nosuffix>
              <closureCompilationLevel>WHITESPACE_ONLY</closureCompilationLevel>
              <webappSourceDir>src/main/resources/public/app</webappSourceDir>
              <webappTargetDir>${project.build.outputDirectory}/public/app</webappTargetDir>

              <cssSourceDir>./</cssSourceDir>
              <cssSourceIncludes>
                <cssSourceInclude>**/*.css</cssSourceInclude>
              </cssSourceIncludes>

              <jsSourceDir>./</jsSourceDir>
              <jsSourceIncludes>
                <jsSourceInclude>**/*.js</jsSourceInclude>
              </jsSourceIncludes>

              <jsEngine>CLOSURE</jsEngine>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
              <goal>minify</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
 <!-- minify plugin end -->
```

Comment: *basedir ./src/main/resources/public/app/. does not exist*. That's clear no? Does the folder exist?

Comment: Yes, it does exist, otherwise the project could not be build when I execute mvn clean install in the project. The problem must be with the path concerning the reactor- project.

Answer (score 7):

I was able to reproduce your issue and **fix it** by changing the configuration entry below

```
<webappSourceDir>src/main/resources/public/app</webappSourceDir>
```

to

```
<webappSourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/public/app</webappSourceDir>
```

That is, adding the standard `${project.basedir}` property as a prefix.

With that, the build was successful from the module itself but also from the parent one (the reactor/aggregator build).

Thanks to this prefix, the reactor build will properly resolve the path, pointing at the current base directory (the one of the concerned module) during the build.

---

From official [Maven Builder model documentation](https://maven.apache.org/components/ref/3-LATEST/maven-model-builder/)

> `{project.basedir}` the directory containing the `pom.xml` file

Hence, the reactor build will replace this property for each module, pointing at the directory containing the module `pom.xml` file (hence, the directory of the module). It will also work properly when executing the build from the module directly, obviously pointing at the current directory.

Also note: `${basedir}` would also work but it is deprecated in favor of `project.basedir`, hence better to use the latter.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will test it and afterwards will give you the 100 Points.

Comment: @user3318489 glad to see it helped out!, since you assigned the bounty I guess it was fine as a solution. In that case I would also suggest to accept it as answer √ so that the question doesn't statistically appear as unanswered. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cam minify as:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>com.samaxes.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>minify-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.4</version>
            <executions>
               <execution>
                  <id>minify-css</id>
                  <configuration>
                     <charset>utf-8</charset>
                     <skipMerge>true</skipMerge>
                     <statistics>true</statistics>
                     <cssSourceDir>css</cssSourceDir>
                     <cssTargetDir>css/min</cssTargetDir>
                     <cssSourceIncludes>
                        <cssSourceInclude>*.css</cssSourceInclude>
                     </cssSourceIncludes>
                  </configuration>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>minify</goal>
                  </goals>
               </execution>
               <execution>
                  <id>minify-js-cfl</id>
                  <configuration>
                     <charset>utf-8</charset>
                     <skipMerge>true</skipMerge>
                     <statistics>true</statistics>
                     <jsSourceDir>js/xyz/modules/cfl</jsSourceDir>
                     <jsTargetDir>js/xyz/modules/cfl/min</jsTargetDir>
                     <jsSourceIncludes>
                        <jsSourceInclude>*.js</jsSourceInclude>
                     </jsSourceIncludes>
                  </configuration>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>minify</goal>
                  </goals>
               </execution>
               <execution>
```